# Express.js next(err) not working

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

Here's my code

```
mysql = require('mysql');
con = mysql.createConnection(connectionSetttings);

app.get('/users/list', ensureLogin, function (req, res, next) {
    con.query(query.getUserList, [req.user.innId], function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);  // also tried: return next(err)
        } else {
            displayUsers();
        }
    });
}, function (err) {
    console.error(err);
    displayErrorPage(500);
});
```

I run it with the MySQL server not running to see if Express would render the error page or not. The problem is, Express simply barfs up the stack into the browser. Is there anything wrong with my code? How do I properly chain middlewares?

Comment: Please provide your the code for the middleware you wish to handle the exception

Comment: There near the bottom. The one with `displayErrorPage(500)`.

Answer (score 2):

> Define error-handling middleware functions in the same way as other middleware functions, except error-handling functions have four arguments instead of three: (err, req, res, next).

Make sure to add the error handling to the app `after`the routes.

```
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/users/list', ensureLogin, function (req, res, next) {
  con.query(query.getUserList, [req.user.innId], function (err, rows) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      displayUsers();
    }
  });
});

// Error handling middleware
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  displayErrorPage(500);
});
```

Comment: But now the routes for static files go haywire.

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont know the technical meaning behind 'haywire'. So without some content from DisplayErrorPage or how you serve the static files. This boils down to wild guesses

Comment: The routes for files such as CSS, JavaScripts and images are throwing error 500.

Comment: All of the middlewares added by app.use wil run for all of the requests. You can fix this by either pas the exception to displayErrorPage and see that it has a value, or attach the middleware to the specific route

Comment: I've been trying to attach the handler only to specific routes, like I did in the code I put on my question above. The problem is, Express still throw the error onto the page.

Comment: does the code in displayErrorPage get executed? Do you render or use res.send to the client? do you call next() in the function? Does the function execute when you load static files? please dude, provide information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134984/discussion-between-starleaf1-and-r-gulbrandsen).

Answer (score 0):

When using MySQL as a session store, session-related middlewares attached using `app.use()`  will intercept requests for all routes and malfunctions. This will make seemingly unrelated routes throw `HTTP500` even if it doesn't look like they invoke `return next(err)`.

The solution to this is to only attach any session-related middleware to necessary routes. Alternatively, you can wrap them in a filter function like this one:

```
var middlewareFilter = function(middleware) {
    // Return whatever function that is returned by this function
    // to be used in app.use()
    return function (req, res, next) {
        // Set the routes to be ignored.
        var exceptionList = [
            'images',
            'stylesheets',
            'scripts'
        ];

        // Cast req.url to string so it can use JS's string methods
        var path = String(req.url);

        // If path matches any of the exceptionList...
        if (array.contains(path.split('/')[1], exceptionList)) {
            // ...just do nothing
            return next();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, return the middleware
            return middleware(req, res, next);
        }
    }
}
```

And use them like `app.use(session(sessionConfig));`